# Ordering by rownumber in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to assing a ROW_NUMBER() in sql according to the number of rows by a particular other field. If I choose (order by that_field) then it just reorganizes the order of that field relative to the rownumber.

Example:

What I dont want

```
A1 \ 1...
A1 \ 2...
A1 \ 3...
A1 \ 4...
A2 \ 5...
A2 \ 6...
A2 \ 7...
A3 \ 8...
```

What I do want

```
A1 \ 1...
A1 \ 2...
A1 \ 3...
A1 \ 4...
A2 \ 1...
A2 \ 2...
A2 \ 3...
A3 \ 1...
```

Essentially, I want the rownumber to restart everytime the field changes value. 
Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I removed the mysql tag because MySQL does not support `row_number()` so the question cannot be about that database.

Answer (score 5):

You want `partition by`:

```
select row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2)
```